# Setting up a macro for the pivot chart

Tags: excel, vba

I need to set up a macro for excel pivots charts. I need to change the complete format of the charts. If anybody could provide with solution I would provide with the data that has to be created. I have done my part of work halfway would like to know if anybody could help out with it. The charts that need to be changed are pivots. There are plenty of charts so cannot be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

Code for pivot tables and pivot charts is complicated, it's best to use the macro recorder to record what you want to do once and then to generalize the code manually.